# Sending form to e-mail

Tags: php, forms, email, jquery

I'm trying to send a form to a e-mail using AJAX.
Problem : I'm not reciving the e-mail.
Obs.: The form is in portguese just ignore the text part ;)

index.html

```
    ...
<head>
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/javascript.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="ajax_form" action="">
 <div class="contentformleft" align="left">
 <font size="4"  >Nome :</font></br>
 <input type="text" required  name="nome" size="60"><br><br>
 <font   size="4" >E-mail :</font></br>
 <input type="text" required  name="email" size="60"><br><br>

 <font   size="4"  >Curso :</font><br>
 <select name="cursos" style="width: 395px" class="auto-style1">
 <option>Sistemas de Informação</option>
 </select><br><br>

 <font   size="4"  >Turno :</font> </br>
 <font size="3">
 <input type="radio" name="turno" value="1"></input>Manha   
 <input type="radio" name="turno" value="2"></input>Noite<br>
 </font></br>

 <font   size="4"  >Área de Interesse<font size="2"  >(max 2)</font> : </br>
 <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" /> CIO<br />


 <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" /> Hardware<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" /> Sistemas Empresariais<br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="interesse" /> Redes Sociais e Mobile<

br />

     <input id="Send" class="btn" type="submit" value="Enviar"></input>
     <font size="3" color="red">As Inscrições comecaram dia 26</font>
     </form>
...
<script src="scripts/jqueryscript.min.js"></script> 
     ...
```

jqueryscript.min.js

```
...
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
        var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sender.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function( data )
            {
                alert( data );
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
...
```

sender.php

```
<?php
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $curso = $_POST['cursos'];
    $turno = $_POST['turno'];
    $interesse = $_POST['interesse'];

    $mensagem = '<html><body>';
    $mensagem .= '<h1 style="font-size:15px;">Formulario :</h1>';
    $mensagem .= '<table style="border-color: #666; font-size:11px" cellpadding="10">';
    $mensagem .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Nome:</strong> </td><td>' . $nome . '</td></tr>';
    $mensagem .= '<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>' . $email . '</td></tr>';
    $mensagem .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Curso:</strong> </td><td>' . $curso . '</td></tr>';
    $mensagem .= '<tr><td><strong>Turno:</strong> </td><td>' . $turno . '</td></tr>';
    $mensagem .= '<tr style="background: #eee;"><td><strong>Interesse:</strong> </td><td>' . $interesse . '</td></tr>';
    $mensagem .= '</table>';
    $mensagem .= '</body></html>';

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $nome);
    $mail->Subject = 'Inscrição NUTI';
    $mail->MsgHTML($mensagem);
    $mail->AddAddress('brunuwb@gmail.com', 'Bruno');
    $mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);
?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

EXTRA : I want to alert the user that the form was sent. :)

Comment: You could use a tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to monitor the requests and responses, that might help you to see where the problem is. With it you can check if the data actually gets sent or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't `$mail->Send()` you will never get an email!

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom($email, $nome);
$mail->Subject = 'Inscrição NUTI';
$mail->MsgHTML($mensagem);

$mail->AddAddress($email, $nome);

if (!$mail->Send()) {
  // PHPMailer Error!
}
else {
  // Email sent!
}
```

BTW You may implement a command to echo the HTML-Email to the browser, so you can test and see how they will look like (without sending and waiting for emails).